# python substitute an element to a list in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, csv, list-comprehension

I am trying to use a list comprehension to make a list ready for output to csv file.

When I write

```
record[:] = [[', '.join(row)] if element == int(row[4]) else element for element in records]
```

It outputs what I want. But since csv output format needs to have lists in a list, I need to substitute the unchanged 'element' in else part to a list.
I thus, tried

```
record[:] = [[', '.join(row)] if element == int(row[4]) else [element] for element in records]
```

But this does not work. This command cannot recognise and substitute correctly. Some elements found being substituted by the first method are not substituted by this method, which is quite odd.
I thus, was wondering what has happened here.

Thanks.

Comment: You have a typo (extra parenthesis) here: `', '.join(row))`

Comment: @revliscano edited, thanks

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the contents of `row` and `records`?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  What error is being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

It worked well when I tried ur code:

```
row = ['1','2','3','4','5']
records = [6,7,8,9,0,10,5,11,12]

res = [[', '.join(row)] if element == int(row[4]) else element for element in records]
res = [[', '.join(row)] if element == int(row[4]) else [element] for element in records]
```

Maybe u should give a sample of `records` , `row` and `record`